# How do I have a list of strings in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, list

I'm trying to make a punishment system that stores the values in MySQL.
How do I have a list of strings in one column?
I've tried to do this, but then it is limited to however many columns you add in.

```
Username  | Punishment 1       | Punishment 2       | Punishment 3
----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------
Test Acc  | "{'type':'1',...}" | "{'type':'2',...}" | "{'type':'1',...}"
Person239 | "{'type':'3',...}" | "{'type':'1',...}" | "{'type':'2',...}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve this in MySQL, this can be achieved through `JSON`.

In the example provided in the question, a JSON list would work.  For example:

```
Username  | Punishments
----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------
Test Acc  | [{'type':'1',...}, {'type':'2',...}, {'type':'1',...}]
Person239 | [{'type':'3',...}, {'type':'1',...}, {'type':'2',...}]
```

This method allows for an unlimited amount (excluding storage space limitations) of objects (in this example, punishments) to be included in each database row.

The JSON data can then be parsed in your language of choice.

However, as suggested in another answer, a non-relational database may be more suited to this task due to its flexibility.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL version 5.7.8 supports JSON data type. You can store a list of strings in one column.

**Or** You can write your list in your database as plain text, then parse it on the application layer.

**Or** You can instead use PostgreSQL that supports JSONB(JSON Binary).
Note: JSONB supports indexing the JSON data, and is very efficient at parsing and querying the JSON data.

**Or** Use a non-relational database.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

To this approach, perhaps you should consider a non relational database. You will have more flexibility in handling your data.